# Joomla: system SEF module links On/Off + backlinks

Tags: joomla, sef

I want to test whether turning on joomla's SEF links option in global configuration works for my site.

If it doesn't work... can I just turn it back off again without issue? 
I don't want to accidentally break my site entirely.

Also - are backlinks maintained when it's turned on for anyone linking to the old non-sef links?

(using Joomla 1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning SEF URL's on and off is a simple task. If you need to switch from one to the other, it's a simple click of a radio button.

The only problem being though is that some components do not support SEF URL's. Most do but there might be some on your site that unfortunately don't. So make sure yo test all links. If some don't work, just turn SEF off